# Form model binding not working in laravel 5.2 using laravelcollective

Tags: laravel

Hello I'm new to `laravel` 5.2 and going through some lessons.

For some reason form model binding is not working for me.

```
{!! Form::model($post, ['method'=>'PATCH', 'action'=> ['PostController@update', $post->id]]) !!}
```

I received data in `$post` because I'm using a workaround like this:

```
{!! Form::text('title', "$post->title" ,['class'=> 'form-control']) !!}
```

And that is showing my data.

Controller:

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Post;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Requests;

class PostController extends Controller{
    public function update(Request $request, $id){
        $post =Post::findOrfail($id);
        $post->update($request->all());
        return redirect('/posts');
    }
}
```

create.blade.php view:

```
@section('content')
<h1>Create Post</h1>
{!! Form::open(['method'=>'POST', 'action'=>'PostController@store']) !!}
    <!-- Title Form Input -->
    <div class="form-group">
        {!! Form::label('title', 'Title:') !!}
        {!! Form::text('title', 'null', ['class'=> 'form-control']) !!}
    </div>
    <!--  Form Input -->
    <div class="form-group">
        {!! Form::submit('Create Post', ['class'=> 'btn-primary form-control']) !!}
    </div>
{!! Form::close() !!}
@endsection
```

Comment: Are we talking about `laravelcollective/html` composer package? Could you post the entire section of your form, including how you are treating data on controller part?

Comment: Thanks for your feedabck phaberest and yes i'm using lavavelcollective/html

Answer (score 4):

You shouldn't be quoting the value for `null` in your input:

```
{!! Form::text('title', 'null', ['class'=> 'form-control']) !!}
```

should be

```
{!! Form::text('title', null, ['class'=> 'form-control']) !!}
```

Comment: god bless you!!

Answer (score 0):

Ok, try adding the body of the form into a partial called `posts/partials/form.blade.php`and include it between the form open / model and form close tags.

Example:

`posts/partials/form.blade.php`

```
<!-- Title Form Input -->
<div class="form-group">
    {!! Form::label('title', 'Title:') !!}
    {!! Form::text('title', 'null', ['class'=> 'form-control']) !!}
</div>
<!--  Form Input -->
<div class="form-group">
    {!! Form::submit($formButtonText, ['class'=> 'btn-primary form-control']) !!}
</div>
```

`posts/create.blade.php`

```
{!! Form::open(['method'=>'POST', 'action'=>'PostController@store']) !!}

@include('posts.partials.form', [
    'formSubmitButtonText' => 'Create Post'
])


{!! Form::close() !!}
```

`posts/edit.blade.php`

```
{!! Form::model($post, ['method'=>'PATCH', 'action'=> ['PostController@update', $post->id]]) !!}
@include('posts.partials.form', [
    'formSubmitButtonText' => 'Update Post'
])
{!! Form::close() !!}
```

Comment: Thanks Ruffles, much cleaner option but form::model does still not work. Return null.

Comment: Still no idea what is wrong. I've tried to get this work with a new laravel install native on my machine or with homested with same results.

Comment: That's strange. Do you have a field called title in your posts table?

Comment: Yes i have. i have a kolom called title it's a varchar